# boost: Initializing shared pointer reset vs make_shared

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

Apart of the size of generated code, what's the difference between using `reset()` for initializing a shared pointer over the function `make_shared()`?

**Case 1** by using `reset()`

```
boost::shared_ptr<A> pA;
pA.reset(new A());
```

**Case 2** by using `make_shared()`

```
boost::shared_ptr<A> pA;
pA = boost::make_shared<A>();
```

In general, is it a good practice to use `reset` over `make_shared` to reduce the size of executable?

Comment: `make_shared` is more efficient. Use that.

Comment: @KerrekSB, it depends how you measure efficiency, `make_shared` does fewer allocations and reduces heap footprint, but typically increases code size, which has its own cost. [Template Code Bloat Revisited: A Smaller make_shared](http://articles.emptycrate.com/2015/04/27/template_code_bloat_revisited_a_smaller_makeshared.html) is an interesting read.

Comment: @KerrekSB what do you mean with "more efficient"? If I compare the amount of generated code, the reset is smaller.

Comment: @lucab0ni, but if you count the number of calls to `malloc`, or the total size requested from `malloc`, then `make_shared` is smaller.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**`reset(new T(...))`** allocates a heap block, constructs the object, allocates a new heap block for the reference counter and initializes the reference counter.

**`make_shared<T>(...)`** allocates a heap block slightly larger than required for the object and constructs the object and the reference counter in the same heap block.

The chance is high that `make_shared()` runs faster and requires less memory.

*But there is a small drawback* if you are using an IDE like Microsoft Visual Studio: Intellisense is not able to show you the names of the parameters used in the constructor. The code is working correctly but editing the `make_shared()` call is uncomfortable.

Comment: I would give this an upvote but the advice at the end is arbitrary and purely opinion-based.

Comment: You are right. I was not even sure about this advice so I removed it  without substitution.

Comment: For a much better intellisense behavior, use CLion. It is way better than Visual Studio or XCode

Answer (score 4):

`make_shared<T>` creates the reference counter in the same chunk of memory which is allocated for T. It's an optimization. `reset` does not do this.

Comment: "*It's an optimization.*" And sometimes it's a pessimization. ;-]